# why isn't my local variable overwriting the global?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[The code that I'm running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKxmI.png)  how come the local x isn't overwriting the global x?

```
x = 'global x'

def test():
    global x
    x = 'local x'
    print(x)

print(x)
test()
```

---

Output:

```
global x

local x
```

Comment: There's no local variable.

Comment: `local x` is overwrite `global x`. you have to print `print(x)` after you call `test()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is. You're first printing x, which is the global x. Afterwards you're calling test which then prints the local x at the end of the function. Defining the function doesn't mean it gets called.
If you want it to overwrite the global x with the nontest function, try

```
test()

print(x)
```

instead of

```
print(x)

test()
```

Answer (score 3):

Before the `test` function is called, `x = 'global x'` is no problem.

I think you wanna this

```py
x = 'global x'

def test():
    global x
    x = 'local x'
    print(x)

print(x) # Before test call, x = 'global x'
test() # test called, x = 'local x'
print(x) # test called, x overwriting, x = 'local x'
```

Answer (score 1):

after the function call only it will replace the variable, swap the test and print(x) last two line, then you can see the magic

```
x = 'global x'

def test():
    global x
    x = 'local x'
    print(x)

test()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

> The code that I'm running how come the local x isn't overwriting the global x?

The code of the function won't get executed until you call it. Here is the sequence of events in your script.

1. Variable `x` is declared storing an object of type `str` having value `global x`.
2. Interpreter parses the definition of the function `test` but doesn't execute it.
3. You print the value of `x` using `print`.
4. You call the function and it sets the global variable `x` to `local x`.

If you want to change the value of your variable `x` before printing. Do this:

```
x = 'global x'

def test():
    global x
    x = 'local x'
    print(x)

print("Value of x before test:", x)
test() 
print("Value of x after test:", x)
```

Outputs:

```
Value of x before test: global x
local x
Value of x after test: local x
```